# Recursively adding nested lists

Tags: python, list, recursion, nested

I am looking to use a combination of recursion and for-loops to add all the ints in a possibly empty series of nested lists using a function `summer(alist)`. My code so far is:

```
**def summer(alist):**
total=0
print alist
for item in alist:
    if type(item)==list:
        print "The item is a list, containing: "+str(item)
        return sum_nested_list(item)
    elif type(item)==int:
        print item
        total = total + item
print "The total is: "+str(total)
return total
```

My issue is that for example list:

```
list1=[[0,[0,1,1]],[0,1],1]
```

My results are this:

```
[[0,[0,1,1]],[0,1],1]
The item is a list, containing: [0,[0,1,1]]
[0,[0,1,1]]
0
The item is a list, containing [0,1,1]
[0,1,1]
0
1
1
The total is: 2
2
```

How can I get my function to recurse over the **whole** list and not just the first double nested list?

Comment: the problem is that your `return` statement ends the for loop

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I'll try removing that now.

Comment: just posted a possible fix...

Comment: Ah thanks! I tried removing the return and just leaving my `sum_nested_list(item)` out in the cold, and the total would only update for each item and not stay consistent between them. Thanks so much for your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the line:

```
if type(item)==list:
    print "The item is a list, containing: "+str(item)
    return sum_nested_list(item)
```

because return will end the for loop. You can fix this by doing:

```
if type(item)==list:
    print "The item is a list, containing: "+str(item)
    total += sum_nested_list(item)
```

Comment: @Jam You should consider using `isinstance(item, list)` instead of `type(item)==list`. It is more flexible (e.g. `isinstance(item, (list, tuple, set))` and also works for subclasses) and the pythonic way. If you want to check the exact type, use `is`: `type(item) is list`

Comment: @schwobaseggl good point.. do you think I should edit the answer to include this?